# "Pause on uncaught exceptions" is not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I'm trying to understand how the Chrome debugger works and investigated a problem. I have a simple .js code that throws an uncaught error:

```
// Uncaught ReferenceError: the is not defined
console.log(the);
```

The problem comes from the fact that I've check the "Pause on uncaught exceptions" checkbox in the Chrome DevTools but it doesn't seem to pause the app when the error occurs.

If I check the "Pause on caught exception" checkbox though the application is being paused.

Is there something I misunderstood about uncaught errors/the Chrome debugger? I can't believe that there can be such a silly bug in the DevTools, so the problem is most likely in my understanding.